# Проверить запрос к серверу. Пропустить, если он пришёл от мобильного приложения

Tags: php, java, android, безопасность

Есть мобильное приложение, из которого посредством GET-запроса отправляются данные серверному скрипту (скрипт на php), который обрабатывает их и отправляет в базу данных MySQL.
На данный момент, зная ссылку этого запроса, можно просто ввести её в строку браузера и отправить в базу данных какую угодно некорректную информацию.
Как мне сделать так, чтобы сервер принимал и добавлял в базу данных только ту информацию, которая отправляется моим мобильным приложением?

Comment: *Как мне сделать так, чтобы сервер принимал и добавлял в базу данных только ту информацию, которая отправляется моим мобильным приложением?* О каком сервере речь? MySQL-то тут вообще никаким боком, ему задания даёт не приложение, а PHP. Удалите его из тегов-то. А вот PHP уже пусть разбирается, кто с ним разговаривает, и запросы не от приложения - жестоко игнорит.

Comment: Как это реализовать? Нужно же и в приложении что-то менять наверное, чтобы php-скрипт его "узнавал". Как вообще это делают, с помощью чего?

Answer (score 3):

Для того чтобы защитить / проверить запросы которые идут на ваш сервер через API есть несколько методов (более детально изучаем книги и документации...)  Один из важных моментов, ваши запросы должны работать по **`https`**

> HTTP Authentication

а. **Basic Authentication** - самый простой метод, есть много дискуссии на счёт использования данного метода(есть пару проблем с уязвимостью) однако, лучше чем ничего :)
При использовании этого метода отправитель помещает имя пользователя и пароль в заголовок запроса. Имя пользователя и пароль кодируются с помощью `Base64`.

б. **Bearer Authentication** - авторизация происходит по токену который генерируется вашей системой(backend) и все запросы должны иметь данный токен.

в. **REST API Security** на серверной части создаёте уникальный ключ по которому будет работать приложение с бекендом. Обратите внимание, лучший вариант - поместить ключ API в заголовок авторизации вместо отправки в виде параметров(GET/POST)

Есть ещё методы, однако, думаю `Bearer Authentication` или `REST API Security` полностью решат вашу проблему.

Answer (score 1):

Чисто технически невозможно создать такой запрос, который невозможно повторить. Можно лишь усложнять его воспроизведение, хотя это и бессмысленно в общем-то, т.к. повторить всё равно можно. Возможно, вам стоит несколько изменить ТЗ. Если надо, например, только убрать возможность простого вызова из браузера, то сделайте Post запрос вместо Get - браузер умеет только get запрос делать (если имеется в виду вставка и переход по ссылке из адресной строки)